# Load and Activate events for a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having three forms

`1. Main page`

`2. Input page`

`3. Output page`

I want load event to be activated whenever coming from Main page to Inputpage and activate event when coming from output page to input page.
But what i am getting is that only for the first time load is activated and for all other only activate is called.

Comment: Where are your input and output pages created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're saying but if I understand you, you want to execute the contents of a load event more than once?  Maybe can you just create a private sub and put what you need to be executed in that and then call it to execute the code? Works for me when I need to refresh a dataset that is filled when the form load event occurs.

```
Private Sub loadevent
' put code you want to be executed again here
End Sub

Private Sub button_click
loadevent()
End Sub
```

Not to sure, sorry..

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design.  The load event occurs before a form is displayed for the first time([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events.aspx)) and only is fired once.  As for the events you might want to use instead, look at the link I included and see what fits your cicumstances the best.